# quit in .gdbinit

Tags: gdb

I have composed a `.gdbinit` file that contains commands to be executed by `gdb`:

```
file program
run arg1 arg2
bt
quit
```

The problem is that `quit` performs successfully if `program` crashes and would not perform if `program` completed successfully.

I need `quit` to complete in either case. How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that quit performs successfully if program crashes and would not perform if program completed successfully.

This is because `bt` causes an error if program completed successfully. It cause `No stack` error:

```
.gdbinit:3: Error in sourced command file:
No stack.
```

and subsequent `quit` does not get executed because of an error.

You can use `$_isvoid` and `$_exitsignal` variables to fix your `.gdbinit` script:

```
file program
run arg1 arg2
if $_isvoid ($_exitsignal)
 echo The program has exited\n
 else
 echo The program has signalled\n
 bt
end
quit
```

See documentation for [Convenience Variables](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html).

Comment: In case the program has crashed in the following way `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.` I get a report `The program has exited` and no trace.